# Have sub report overflow to separate page

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a Report with a sub report with details. There is a complex footer area with variables on the page. I want any overflow on the sub report to be created on a second page. What is the easiest approach?

Answer (score 0):

So yeah the solution was to drop reporting services and move to Itextsharp. Good Times.